# Problem with sending data from Angular to Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to post data from Angular to Express.js

This is my function connected to the button (TypeScript):

```
  upload(): void {
    const nameFromId = document.getElementById('taskName') as HTMLInputElement;
    this.taskName = nameFromId.value;

    const testData = [
      {
        task: this.taskName,
        selectedType: this.selectedType,
        selectedSubject: this.selectedSubject
      }
    ];
    const body = JSON.stringify(testData);
    this.http.post('/api/upload', body)
      .subscribe();
```

"body" is not null

This is express:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.post('/api/upload', (req, res) => {
  let task = req.body.task;
  let selectedType = req.body.selectedType;
  let selectedSubject = req.body.selectedSubject;

  console.log("task: " + task);
  console.log("type: " + selectedType);
  console.log("subject: " + selectedSubject);
  console.log("server: " + req.body);
  res.end("yes");
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/al'));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/al/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port);
```

And this is what I get as a mistake:

[mistake from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qyQf.png)

If I put extra options to my "post method" from Angular and write something like:

```
this.http.post('/api/upload', body, {responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe();
```

After adding responseType: 'text' this mistake is no longer exists, but when it comes to console.log all data, that I posted to express, undefined:

[Express console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOHkJ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, it seems like your req.body does not contain any "task", "type" or "subject". You could console.log JSON.stringify(req.body) to see what's inside of the actual object (and not get "[object Object]"

Comment: It shows that body contains: {}

Comment: My initial intuitive guess would be that you can't send an array as the top level 'container' of a post request. Try just sending the one object and see what happens.

Comment: Cody, I've just tried it, but still has undefined on post request from Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a string as http request body.
Don't use JSON.stringify, try sending object as is.

```
const testData = [
      {
        task: this.taskName,
        selectedType: this.selectedType,
        selectedSubject: this.selectedSubject
      }
    ];

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
}

this.http.post('/api/upload', testData, httpOptions)
  .subscribe();
```

Also add this line to server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Finally:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: I've just tried it, but still doesn't work

Comment: Are you using body-parser module before post middleware?

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: andellapie, no I'm not. But I've just tried to use it and it still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated my answer with httpOptions. Give it a try

Comment: andellapie, I've just updated my program and my post above, but still can only get undefined. I think that I've got a problem with my front end post request. Because at express even when I used JSON.parse(req.body) - it showed "{}"

Comment: @GlKosh I've updated my answer. It should work now. Pay attention! You are trying to access req.body.task as object, but your are sending an array